# Set Background Color of a clicked table cell

Tags: java, jtable, cell, background-color

I'm new to Java and I want to change the background color of a Specific cell, the one I clicked on, of a `JTable`.

I know that I have to use a `MouseListener` which I already did, also, the `mousePressed`. But at this point I am pretty lost.

**EDIT:** Forgot to add that the table is disabled, so you can't select a cell.

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create a custom `TableCellRenderer` and pass it to the table

like this

```
public class ColorRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col)  {
       // get the DefaultCellRenderer to give you the basic component
       Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, col);
       // apply your rules
       if(table.isRowSelected(row) && table.isColumnSelected(col))
          c.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
       else{    
           c.setBackground(table.getBackground());
       }

       return c;
    }
}
```

in this class we check if the given cell if the selected cell (which is pretty much what happens when we click it) and paint it differently (in my case I paint it green)  , else we paint with the default color or any color you like.

don't forget to set the custom renderer you just created

```
table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new ColorRenderer());
```

## Edit 1

you must get the row and col of the clicked cell.

create 2 int variables that will hold the position

```
private int clickedRow=-1,clickedCol=-1;
```

add a mouse listener that updates the position variables

```
table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
                clickedRow= table.rowAtPoint(event.getPoint());
                clickedCol= table.columnAtPoint(event.getPoint());
            }
});
```

after that you change the renderer so it paints only the clicked cell with the special color

```
if( clickedRow == row && clickedCol == col){
    c.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I forgot to add that the whole table is disabled, so its not possible to "select" a cell, only to click on it. Is that even possible?

Comment: I have updated my answer. I haven't actually tried the second way, tell me if it works.